# SVG with square viewBox overflowing viewPort

Tags: css, svg, aspect-ratio

A have a non-squared svg and need a square (unit) `viewBox` that may be overflowing the `viewPort`. What can I do? I tried all options of `preserveAspectRatio`, which didn't work. Any other ideas would be much appreciated.

This is how it should be looking...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
```

slice ensures that the all the viewport is visible within the viewBox.